# Dynamic Oracle Pivot_In_Clause

Tags: oracle-11g-r2, pivot

I'm kinda stuck. I want to do a user-role-relationship pivot table and my query so far looks like this:

```
WITH PIVOT_DATA AS (
     SELECT *
     FROM
     (
         SELECT USERNAME, GRANTED_ROLE
         FROM DBA_USERS@DB_LINK U LEFT OUTER JOIN DBA_ROLE_PRIVS@DB_LINK R
         ON U.USERNAME = R.GRANTEE
      )
)
SELECT *
FROM PIVOT_DATA
PIVOT
(
    COUNT(GRANTED_ROLE)
    FOR GRANTED_ROLE
    IN('CONNECT') -- Just an example
)
ORDER BY USERNAME ASC;
```

It works really fine and does the job, but I don't want to write to write any role I want to search for in the `pivot_in_clause`, because we got like tons of them and I don't want to check every time if there are any changes.

So is there a way to write a `SELECT` in the `pivot_in_clause`? I tried it myself:

```
[...]
PIVOT
(
    COUNT(GRANTED_ROLE)
    FOR GRANTED_ROLE
    IN( SELECT ROLE FROM DBA_ROLES@DB_LINK )
)
[...]
```

But it always gives me an ORA-00936: "missing expression" in line 1 of the whole query and I don't know why. Can't there be a `SELECT` in the `pivot_in_clause` or am I doing it wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to implement some sort of dynamic list of columns for a PIVOT, then you can look at using a procedure that generates dynamic SQL. The basic syntax of the procedure will be:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE procedure dynamic_pivot(p_cursor in out sys_refcursor)
as
    sql_query varchar2(1000) := 'select USERNAME ';

    begin
        for x in (select distinct ROLE from DBA_ROLES@DB_LINK)
        loop
            sql_query := sql_query ||
                ' , sum(case when GRANTED_ROLE = '''||x.Role||''' then 1 else 0 end) as '||x.Role;

                dbms_output.put_line(sql_query);
        end loop;

        sql_query := sql_query || ' FROM DBA_USERS@DB_LINK U 
                                    LEFT OUTER JOIN DBA_ROLE_PRIVS@DB_LINK R
                                      ON U.USERNAME = R.GRANTEE
                                    GROUP BY USERNAME';
        dbms_output.put_line(sql_query);

        open p_cursor for sql_query;
    end;
/
```

Then you can test the result using:

```
variable x refcursor
exec dynamic_pivot(:x)
print x;
```

This will gives a result similar to this:

```
+----------+-----+-------+-------+
| Username | DBA | Owner | Admin |
+----------+-----+-------+-------+
| Bob      |   0 |     0 |     1 |
| Jane     |   1 |     1 |     1 |
| Jim      |   1 |     1 |     0 |
+----------+-----+-------+-------+
```

Answer (score 3):

This may or may not help you, but with `PIVOT XML` instead of the simple `PIVOT` you can do what you want.

> Adding the XML keyword to the PIVOT operator allows us to convert the
>   generated pivot results to XML format. It also makes the PIVOT a
>   little more flexible, allowing us to replace the hard coded IN clause
>   with a subquery, or the ANY wildcard.

([source](http://www.oracle-base.com/articles/11g/pivot-and-unpivot-operators-11gr1.php))

This will return obviously an XML, this is why it may not help you...

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I forgot to mention that I already tried `PIVOT XML` but for some reason, I don't know, it cuts of my output after something like 80 characters.

Comment: That must be some client strangness.  Try to fiddle around with its preferences.